# How do strings look from the compiler's point of view?

Tags: c#, .net, string, memory, compiler-construction

In `C`, the compiler has a pointer to the start of the string and has an end-symbol (`'\0'`). If a user wants to calculate the length of the string, the compiler has to count elements of the string array until it finds `'\0'`.

In `UCSD-strings`, the compiler has the length of the string in the first symbols.

And what does the compiler think about `C#-strings`? Yes, from the user's point of view *`String`* is an `object` that has a field *`Length`*, I'm not talking about high-level stuff. I want to know deep algorithms; e.g., how does the compiler calculate the length of the string?

Comment: Your C assumption is wrong. A C compiler knows **exactly** how long each string is. To see this, call `sizeof` on the string (not on a _pointer to_ the string!).

Comment: Normally, I would close this as a dupe but the duplicates are bad. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3377/Strings-UNDOCUMENTED

Comment: @MSalters You are confusing concepts. Arrays and strings different entities and they have different operations associated with them. They are related, but they are different abstractions and they shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: @MSalters: I think homk means the implementation of the length (`strlen` in C) function, not the compiler.

Comment: You're mixing up what the compiler sees and what happens at the time of execution. The way the compiler works with strings may bear no resemblance to how functions like `strlen` work with them, and the compile-time and run-time representations may be completely different.

Comment: "In С, the compiler has a pointer to the start of the string and has an end-symbol ('\0')". No. In C the compiler has a start quote and an end quote. It will deliver the number of characters in between as the `sizeof` result, no matter what they are, including embedded nulls. `strlen()` has nothing to do with it, and neither do pointers. The compiler will also *place* a trailing null into the compiled string. It isn't there in the source text.

Comment: @PaulManta: Disagree. C doesn't provide a string abstraction; in order to work reliably with strings, one must understand that one is working with character arrays in a conventional manner.

Comment: @Hurkyl Example of why arrays and strings are not the same: `sizeof(x)` will never be equal to `strlen(x)` for any string `x`.

Comment: @PaulManta: To the compiler (which is the subject of the question), strings are a special case of arrays. Different syntax, same operations. `strlen` is not a compiler concern.

Comment: @MSalters Oh, I see. I somehow missed the emphasis on "compiler". I was still thinking about run-time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's execute the following code:

```
string s = "123";
string s2 = "234";
string s3 = s + s2;
string s4 = s2 + s3;
Console.WriteLine(s + s2);
```

Now let's put a breakpoint at the last line and open the memory window:

[image: Strings]

Writing `s3` in the memory window we can see the 2 (`s3` and `s4`) strings allocated one after the other with 4 bytes of size at the beginning.

Also you can see that other memory is allocated such as the `strings` class type token and other `string` class data.

The [`string` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55b2f6374a7cf7c1) itself contains a member `private int  m_stringLength;` which contains the length of the `string`, this also makes `string.Concat()` execute super fast (by allocating the whole length at the beginning):

```
int totalLength = str0.Length + str1.Length + str2.Length;

String result = FastAllocateString(totalLength);
FillStringChecked(result, 0, str0);
FillStringChecked(result, str0.Length, str1);
FillStringChecked(result, str0.Length + str1.Length, str2);
```

What I find a little strange is that the implementation of `IEnumerable<char>.Count()` for `string` is done using the default implementation which means iterating items one by one unlike `ICollection<T>`s like `List<T>` where the `IEnumerable<char>.Count()` is implemented by taking its `ICollection<T>.Count` property.

Comment: @homk If that's what you wanted to know, your real question has nothing to do with 'from the compiler's point of view' whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

In C# the length of the string is stored in the object in a private field (`[NonSerialized]private int  m_stringLength;`), it doesn't have to be calculated at run-time.

[The source code of String class is available online.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c)